# windows form button show textbox and add name for new button

Tags: c#, button, textbox, panel

I have a vertical panel and it has a button, that button must display a textbox that will insert the name and create a button inside the panel

I have no idea how to show textbox and one button to create a button on it = /

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (textBox1.Visible)

                textBox1.Visible = false;
                else
                    textBox1.Visible = true;


            Button c = new Button();
            c.Location = new Point(15, x);
            c.Text = "novo"; //here comes with the button name, need textbox receives the name and create a button with the name of the textbox.
            panel1.Controls.Add(c);

            x += 10 + c.Size.Height;




        }
```

Comment: with name of text box or text of the text box??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write following codes if u want to show text of the text box

```
    Button c = new Button();
    c.Location = new Point(15, x);
    c.Text = textBox1.Text; 
    panel1.Controls.Add(c);

    x += 10 + c.Size.Height;
```

and write following codes if u want to show name of the text box

```
    Button c = new Button();
    c.Location = new Point(15, x);
    c.Text = textBox1.Name.ToString(); 
    panel1.Controls.Add(c);

    x += 10 + c.Size.Height;
```